# Charting Components For Sharepoint 2013 and Office 365

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I am currently searching for some clientside charting components that are free that we can use to display statistics etc.

Could anyone recommend any that are available. If they have the capability of writing custom code and a gui interface that would be great.

The will be used for websites.

[Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/buy/#!website-apps) 
This is not free but an example of what we would like.

[Kendo UI](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/) 
This is not free but an example of what we would like.

Comment: I've only used this one, and don't know much about it: http://www.jqplot.com.  I would post as an answer, but I wouldn't be able to provide any information other than it was simple enough for me to use with little JavaScript experience.

Comment: Instead of free being a requirement, why don't you look at the ROI and pick the solutions that provide the best value?

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2013 on-premises installation you can use Collabion Charts for SharePoint  http://www.collabion.com/). The trial version never expires so you can use it as long as you wish.